# How to change Select2 default new tags key "tab" to "space"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using tag supporting of Select2 for my tag editor, I know you can add a non-existed tag by enter tag and press key "tab"

My question is: I don't want any tags contain space, such as "space tag", 
so is there any way to set "space" key as a new tag trigger?

Answer (score 9):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> After some digging, I solved my question by

```
$("#e20").select2({
        tags:["red", "green", "blue"],
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
 });
```

> The key point is the `tokenSeparators` attribute.
>
> And the [document of Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html) is useful.

Comment: How to create keydown event in select2? I want to trigger a event for spacebar